# Iterate on modules in Python

Tags: python

So I have a nested folder in which I have modules that perform some action. 
Note: they are not classes it's just scripts.
I would like to iterate on those modules.
What I have now:

```
from scripts.module_1 import train_module_1 
from scripts.module_2  import train_module_2  
from scripts.module_3 import train_module_3
from scripts.module_4 import train_module_4 


def test_train_module_1():
    try:
        train_module_1.main('test.csv')
    except ValueError as value_error:
        assert False, "test_train_module_1  failed:" + str(value_error)
...
The same for all train modules
```

This is how my dir looks like, My code is written in `my_test.py` :

```
tests
   my_test.py
scripts
   module_1
      __init__.py
      train_module_1.py
      module_1_blabla.py
   module_2
      __init__.py
      train_module_2.py
      module_2_blabla.py
...
```

I wonder if I can somehow iterate on the those modules, in each module
take only the files that starts with "train_"
and perform the main function in each. I basically know how to do it But I didnt find a good solution for this kind of iterations.
I need dynamically to get the modules from scripts. so that even if someone will add a module I won't need to change the code here.

Is there something like that:

```
for i in scripts.children():
    for j in i.children():
        if j.__name__.startswith('train_'):
            try:
                j.main(f'{j.__name__}_test.csv')
            except ValueError as value_error:
                assert False, f'test_{j.__name__}  failed: {value_error}'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several approaches, depending on your exact needs.

You could, for instance, get a list of the module names in your directory and then import them using the built-in function [`__import__('...')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) like so:

```py
for module_name in list:
    mod = __import__(module_name)
    mod.main(module_name + "_test.csv)
```

If, on the other hand, you have already imported the modules, you can find them by looking at `sys.modules` (which is a dictionary of all currently imported modules).

```py
import sys
for name in sys.modules:
    if name.startswith("train_"):
        mod = sys.modules[name]
        mod.main(name + "_test.csv")
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a more complete version that goes through a directory structure and finds all the Python-modules that start with `train_`, imports them, and executes their `main`-function.

```py
import os

for dir in os.scandir('.'):
    if dir.is_dir():
        for file in os.scandir(dir.path):
            if file.name.startswith('train') and file.name.endswith('.py'):
                name = file.name[:-3]      # without the '.py' at the end
                package = __import__(dir.name + '.' + name)
                mod = getattr(package, name)
                mod.main()
```

Note that the `__import__` function returns the base package (i.e. `scripts` in your case), so we have to retrieve the module we want through `getattr()` first.

Comment: Thanks but those modules( .py files) are in a different directory. I can import `from scripts import *` but then still i'm in directories. Add my dir mapping to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need two different things:

- import some modules and only one specific name from each one
- execute the main function from them

The `importlib` module can help for the first part:

```
train = {}
for num in '1234':
    mod = importlib.import_module('script.module_' + i)
    train[i] = getattr(mod, 'train_module_' + i)
```

You can then easily invoke them:

```
for i, t in train.items():
    try:
        t.main('test.csv')
    except ValueError as value_error:
        assert False, f"test_train_module_{i}  failed:" + str(value_error)
```